# Ideal levels of inequality

Tags: inequality

Has any work been done to try to figure out what a productive level of wealth and income inequality is in a country? i.e. the minimum to provide incentive for 'hard' work, and necessary risk taking in investments.

Comment: This isn't a good question because you're not defining "hard work" or "necessary risk" . Maybe you should ask what is the marginal (DGP) return for inequality or something like [that](https://www.cairn.info/revue-d-economie-politique-2015-5-page-633.htm).

Comment: Yuck. “What’s the ideal level of horrible we should be to each other in order to threaten people into working harder?” Just yuck.

Comment: You misunderstand me. There is an idea that owners of capital need a minimum threshold of reward in order to invest and take risks. I don’t mean the workers themselves. I’m on your side, I hate inequality, but I also know that communism doesn’t work, and people need some form of motivation and promise of personal reward. How do we allow for that fair reward, without being unfair to people, planet and future generations? That’s my question.